# .NET MAUI Project Issues

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, blazor, maui

I have added the MAUI workload in Visual Studio 2022 v17.3.0 Preview 1.1 and I have the following set of errors after creating my project.

[image: 206489-image.png]

Errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning NU1505  Duplicate 'PackageDownload' items found. Remove the duplicate items or use the Update functionality to ensure a consistent restore behavior. The duplicate 'PackageDownload' items are: Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 [6.0.3], Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 [6.0.3], Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 [6.0.3], Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 [6.0.3]. MauiApp2    C:\Users\Trevoir\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj 1
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp2    C:\Users\Trevoir\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj 1
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp2    C:\Users\Trevoir\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj 1
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp2    C:\Users\Trevoir\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj 1
> Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-android, net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst   MauiApp2    C:\Users\Trevoir\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj 1
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier android was not recognized.  MauiApp2    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.3.22179.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 112
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.  MauiApp2    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.3.22179.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 112
> Error   NETSDK1139  The target platform identifier maccatalyst was not recognized.  MauiApp2    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.3.22179.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 112

I have done the maui-check and it always ends with the following:
[image: maui-check]

> .NET SDK - Workloads (6.0.200) Checkup...
> x android-aot (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Android.Manifest-6.0.200 : 31.0.200-preview.12.2) not installed.
> x ios (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.iOS.Manifest-6.0.200 : 15.2.200-preview.12.4) not installed.
> x maccatalyst (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.MacCatalyst.Manifest-6.0.200 : 15.2.200-preview.12.4) not installed.
> x tvos (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.tvOS.Manifest-6.0.200 : 15.2.200-preview.12.4) not installed.
> x macos (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.macOS.Manifest-6.0.200 : 12.1.200-preview.12.4) not installed.
> x maui (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-6.0.200 : 6.0.200-preview.12.2441) not installed.
> ! Managing Workload installation from the CLI is NOT recommended.  Instead you should install the latest Visual Studio
> preview to automatically get the newest release of .NET MAUI workloads installed.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: DON'T run mauicheck. NOR any "old" way of getting Maui workload. I recommend **start all over**. UNINSTALL VS Preview. REBOOT pc. Run VS Installer, select  Preview version, and Workload ".NET Multi-platform App UI development". CREATE a new project using "Maui" template. BUILD.

Answer (score 1):

On PC:
IMHO, DON'T run mauicheck. NOR any "old" way of installing Maui workload.

(On Mac, VS 17.3.0 Preview 1.1 still requires a command line step for Android.)

I recommend **start all over**.

- UNINSTALL VS Preview.
- REBOOT pc.
- Run VS Installer, select
- - Preview version, and
- - Workload ".NET Multi-platform App UI development".
- CREATE a new project using "Maui" template.
- BUILD.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to make the suggestion. This unfortunately hasn't worked.

Comment: If you get different errors now (when build), add them to question. My only other idea is to upgrade to Windows 11 - though I am running fine on Windows 10.

Comment: I didn't get any different errors and am running windows 11 I am afraid...

Comment: Seems like something is messed up in the VS or Maui installation. I thought uninstalling VS Preview would eliminate whatever is causing the problem. Maybe google `clear VS cache`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by running the following command in the folder containing the **.csproj** file.

```
 dotnet workload restore
```